# forest(relative.effect()) / Error in result[["model"]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, rjags

I am trying to plot the results of a network meta-analysis. I have successfully generated the rank probabilities for each treatment relative to placebo. However, when I call **forest(relative.effect(results.rank))** I encounter the following error:

`Error in result[["model"]] : subscript out of bounds`

I realise there are many questions on this forum relating to **"subscript out of bounds"** however none that I have applied have adequately solved my issue.

Can I get an indication as to whether this error means there is something wrong with the way I have labeled my variables or do I need to specify in the `forest(relative effect(results.rank))`  line to widen the bounds somehow?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

UPDATE 29 DEC....
Apologies for the minimal context, here is my code:

```
library(gemtc)
library(rjags)
library(readxl)
df<-read_xlsx("...Book1.xlsx")
#Create network model#
nw<-mtc.network(data.ab=df, treatments=unique(df$treatment))
#Build model#
nw.model <- mtc.model(nw, 
                         linearModel = "random",
                         n.chain = 4,
                         type="consistency",
                         likelihood='binom',
                         link="logit")
#Run MCMC#
nw.mcmc <- mtc.run(nw.model, n.adapt = 50, n.iter = 10000, thin = 10)
#Rank treatments#
nw.rank<-rank.probability(nw.mcmc, preferredDirection = -1)
#Plot relative effect#
forest(relative.effect(nw.rank))
```

My data for this issue are:

```
study<-c("Jones", "Jones", "Prieto", "Prieto", "Scott", "Scott", "Mickle", "Mickle", "Yang", "Yang", "Zhao", "Zhao")
sampleSize<-c(3886, 3876, 218, 214, 2040, 2014, 137, 137, 683, 683, 221, 230)
responders<-c(114, 94, 3, 8, 30, 20, 1, 4, 9, 11, 1, 2)
treatment<-c("dx1", "px1", "rx1", "tx1", "rx1", "ax1", "zx1", "tx1", "gx1", "tx1", "ax1", "px1")
df<-as.data.frame(study, sampleSize, responders, treatment)
```

Comment: Please post enough code and example data to reproduce the issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: @andrew_reece Merry Christmas! My apologies - updated code with sample data added to original post. I am a former Stata users moving over into R so this is a teething problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://rdrr.io/cran/gemtc/man/relative.effect.html), the `relative.effect()` function takes

> An object of S3 class `mtc.result` to derive the relative effects from.

In your example, the `nw.mcmc` object is of type `mtc.result`, and `nw.rank` is not.

```r
class(nw.mcmc) # "mtc.result"
class(nw.rank) # "mtc.rank.probability"
```

So, pass `nw.mcmc` in your call to `relative.effect()`.  Also note that the second argument, `t1`, is required, and this is missing in your code:

> `t1`: A list of baselines to calculate a relative effects against. Will be extended to match the length of `t2`.

Calling `forest`/`relative.effect` with the correct object, along with a treatment level as baseline, runs without error:

```r
forest(relative.effect(nw.mcmc, "ax1"))
```

[image]